# Setting initial values in Django Form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Django form:

```
class PlayerForm(forms.Form):
    OPTIONS = MyUser.objects.all()
    players = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                             queryset=OPTIONS)
```

I want the initial values of the players to be checked if `MyUser.player = True`.  How do I set these initial values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `initial` attribute on the `players` field to be a list of the relevant `MyUser` ids. A quick way to do this is to use the `initial` keyword argument of `ModelMultipleChoiceField`:

```
players = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                         queryset=OPTIONS,
                                         initial=[u.pk for u in OPTIONS if u.player])
```